# how can i get rid of an unwanted border around bg image?

Tags: html, css, background

having issues identifying/getting rid of a border around my full screen background image, or finding an alternative for its code that won't cause this problem. sorry, very beginner.

here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <title>xx</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="bg">

    <p>content</p>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  }
  
  .bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 
  
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code it will remove all problem, on using '*' selector it will apply to all the elements in the DOM.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background: blue;

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the margin, you just need to add "*" to your "body, html" styling. This gets rid of the margin/padding for all elements in the dom.

```
body, html, * {
height: 100%;
color: #cccccc;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: this didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: I just want to clarify we're talking about the same thing, are you saying there is a border around the background image or are you talking about the margin/padding of the page itself? I didn't see any border on the background image.

Comment: adding the "*" just separated my content from the bg image as f it wasnt within <div> but ultimately the issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing to add box-sizing property.

At the top of your CSS file add this...

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then add separately

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    height: 100%;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-align: center;
  }
```